# ManageIQ refreshing not working (error "Not allowing worker")

Tags: openshift, manageiq

I made the openshift monitoring instance with ManageIQ. The connection to openshift is succeeded.

[image]

But refreshing the openshift monitoring does not work. The openshift variables show nothing on the dash board. These are the evm.log of ManageIQ logs.

```
 ERROR -- : MIQ(MiqServer#start_algorithm_used_swap_percent_lt_value) Not allowing worker [ManageIQ::Providers::Openshift::ContainerManager::RefreshWorker] to start since system memory usage has exceeded 60% of swap: Total: [1073737728], Used: [846049280]
[----] I, [2017-05-27T06:15:47.397906 #211:2b001244513c]  INFO -- : MIQ(ManageIQ::Providers::Openshift::ContainerManager::EventCatcher.sync_workers) Workers are being synchronized: Current: [], Desired: ["ems_2"]
[----] E, [2017-05-27T06:15:47.398280 #211:2b001244513c] ERROR -- : MIQ(MiqServer#start_algorithm_used_swap_percent_lt_value) Not allowing worker [ManageIQ::Providers::Openshift::ContainerManager::EventCatcher] to start since system memory usage has exceeded 60% of swap: Total: [1073737728], Used: [846049280]
[----] I, [2017-05-27T06:15:47.415801 #211:2b001244513c]  INFO -- : MIQ(MiqGenericWorker.sync_workers) Workers are being synchronized: Current #: [1], Desired #: [2]
[----] E, [2017-05-27T06:15:47.416125 #211:2b001244513c] ERROR -- : MIQ(MiqServer#start_algorithm_used_swap_percent_lt_value) Not allowing worker [MiqGenericWorker] to start since system memory usage has exceeded 60% of swap: Total: [1073737728], Used: [846049280]
[----] I, [2017-05-27T06:15:47.420465 #211:2b001244513c]  INFO -- : MIQ(MiqReportingWorker.sync_workers) Workers are being synchronized: Current #: [0], Desired #: [2]
[----] E, [2017-05-27T06:15:47.420838 #211:2b001244513c] ERROR -- : MIQ(MiqServer#start_algorithm_used_swap_percent_lt_value) Not allowing worker [MiqReportingWorker] to start since system memory usage has exceeded 60% of swap: Total: [1073737728], Used: [846049280]
[----] I, [2017-05-27T06:15:49.532827 #479:2b001244513c]  INFO -- : MIQ(MiqScheduleWorker::Runner#do_work) Number of scheduled items to be processed: 1.
[----] I, [2017-05-27T06:15:49.546516 #479:2b001244513c]  INFO -- : MIQ(MiqQueue.put) Message id: [929],  id: [], Zone: [default], Role: [smartstate], Server: [], Ident: [generic], Target id: [], Instance id: [], Task id: [job_dispatcher], Command: [JobProxyDispatcher.dispatch], Timeout: [600], Priority: [20], State: [ready], Deliver On: [], Data: [], Args: []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that worker, which takes care of refreshing, is not starting at all due to the insufficient resources on Manage IQ server. If your swap is more than 60% full (seen from the log) then the services already used all of your RAM.

You can get Basic ManageIQ server requirements for each type of server (Vagrant, Docker, Public cloud) here: http://manageiq.org/docs/get-started